# How to add the Connection Driver to my Project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans

I am using NetBeans to test a JSP project. I'm simply trying to establish a connection to the MySQL database that is running on my local machine.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Database connection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% 
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
    String user  = "root";
    String pass  = "root";

    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,user,pass);
    %>   
</body>
</html>
```

NetBeans was able to connect to the server and all of its databases. As seen in the picture below. Is there a way to use the connector driver that Netbeans is using to connect to the database in my project?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you add a jar file to your project ?

Comment: yes I did by right clicking the Libraries folder and clicking Add JAR/Folder

Comment: I didn't understand what you want ? do you want to use this jar in another IDE ?

Comment: I want to know if I have done something wrong because it doesn't work when I deploy

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is the undesired behavior?  What is the error message?  What actions do you perform leading up to the problem?

Comment: it's recommanded that you put your java code in a java class then pass the data to jsp

Comment: try to work with a simple java project to learn how to connect to database

this is a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: yea I get you want to have it stuffed in class and not on the jsp but does that cause the above error?

Comment: I don't know it will be the same error or no but you should learn how to connect to database first

Comment: Well thank you for the help I have to make certain that I can perform CRUD but as of right now encapsulating it has appeared to bear fruit....

Comment: the jar file should be putted in the web-inf/lib folder !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the driver name with appropriate package name. Because the mysql-connector.jar file contains lot of Driver class implementations. So,

Try this code

```
 try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "root", "root");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // perform required operation

 } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
   }
```

Comment: I found that out, by looking at the example in the the link Taha had provided, this is the correct solution to the problem I was encountering.